# Jekyll - Erros com caminhos

Tags: url, jekyll, blog

Estou desenvolvendo um *blog* em *Jekyll* e está dando alguns erros com as *URL's*.

Quando uso `{{ site.url }}` e não coloco a barra depois dessa variável, os caminhos ficam da seguinte maneira: localhost:4000assets, só que quando compilo a versão de produção, os caminhos ficam certos:

Exemplos de como usei as variáveis:

```
{% for post in paginator.posts  %}
  <h2>
    <a href="{{site.url}}{{ post.url |  slugify}}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  </h2>
{% endfor %}
```

**Exemplo de como fica**:

- Versão produção: http://www.brunofolle.com.br/assets/images/default.png
- Versão localhost : http://localhost:4000/assets/images/default.png

Outra dúvida relacionada a isso, é que baixei um *plugin* que gera o `sitemap.xml` e `robots.txt` e utiliza o `site.url` para criação dos mesmos. Porém, os caminhos estão saindo no formato: `http://www.brunofolle.com.br//contato`

**Link do robots.txt e sitemap.xml:**

- http://www.brunofolle.com.br/robots.txt
- http://www.brunofolle.com.br//sitemap.xml

Esse é as configurações de *URL* no `_config.yml`:

```
url: "http://www.brunofolle.com.br/"
baseurl: "/" 
permalink: /:title/
```

Já tentei tirar a barra do base *URL*, e a barra de inicio do *permalink* mas não resolveu.

Alguém tem alguma idéia?

Answer (score 0):

Vou responder minha pergunta porque consegui resolver... Caso outras pessoas tenham o mesmo problema, talvez essa resposta ajude-as.

Pois bem, no `{{ post.url |  slugify}}` eu retirei a o slugify, deixando-o dessa forma: `{{ post.url }}`.

E o *_config.yml* ficou assim:

```
url: "https://brunofolle.com.br"
baseurl: "/" 
permalink: /:title/
```